# Can I initialize a pydantic model using the "unaliased" attribute name?

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm working with an API where the schema for creating a group is effectively:

```
class Group(BaseModel):
  identifier: str
```

I was hoping I could do this instead:

```
class Group(BaseModel):
  groupname: str = Field(..., alias='identifier')
```

But with that configuration it's not possible to set the attribute value using the name `groupname`. That is, running this fails with a `field required` error:

```
>>> g = Group(groupname='foo')
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Group
identifier
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Is it is possible to use *either* the alias or the actual attribute name to set the attribute value? I was hoping that these two would be equivalent:

```
>>> Group(identifier='foo')
>>> Group(groupname='foo')
```

Comment: Hmmm, according to [this](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#model-signature) the alias will be used over the field in the signature unless the alias is not a valid python identifier (and the field is)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the [`allow_population_by_field_name` config option](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/):

> whether an aliased field may be populated by its name as given by the model attribute, as well as the alias (default: `False`)

```python
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Group(BaseModel):
    groupname: str = Field(..., alias='identifier')

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True


print(repr(Group(identifier='foo')))
print(repr(Group(groupname='bar')))
```

Output:

```
Group(groupname='foo')
Group(groupname='bar')
```

Comment: Note that this will now raise a `UserWarning` in `pydantic` V2. You should use `populate_by_name` instead. [Source](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/config/#pydantic.config.ConfigDict.populate_by_name)